# Creating a dynamic "View" for a sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library that has a few custom columns. Is it possible to create a link to that library such that it will impose a view based on the values in the columns?  For example, I have a column titled "email"; if the url to the library was `widgetSP.com/docLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx`, could I create a link with an href similar to `href="widgetSP.com/docLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx&email=billy@gmail.ca"`?

I have some familiarity with jQuery for SharePoint services, but I have no idea if that will help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant do that, You can Use DispForm.aspx or EditForm.Aspx along with and ID query string, but not with other columns of the form, that is just not possible out of the box.